# How to get blurred background on WP8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How do we get that awesome blur effect in our apps? I don't think a blurred PNG file is the solution - or is it?

Below is a sample of what I'm talking about. I found it on [this](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/design/process) page.

Edit: I cannot seem to get SO to upload an image so I will keep trying in the meantime, but you can see the picture I'm referring to via the link above, just scroll down a bit to just above the "prototype" section where it shows pics for the Cocktail app.

Comment: I don't know the app, but if you ask me, that blur was done in a regular image editing software like photoshop and used as a background for a pivot control. If you really want a dynamic blur, you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524863/blur-background-with-viewbox). It is WPF and therefore for the desktop but it gives a good idea how to do a glass effect with blur. But be careful that one was expensive on the pc already.

Comment: @dowhilefor hmm, okay I'll give it a go. I was hoping to be able to have a Panel-like control/overlay and blur it - or something.

Comment: i updated my answer with an idea for a dynamic solution. But again, i wouldn't recommend it. There is no point in using a dynamic runtime solution if you can "bake" it at compile time.

Comment: Is the system.windows.media.effects `BlurEffect` notavailable in wp8? hmmm that's a shame since it's in SL

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the original app to which you linked used a blurred image (i.e. the image had a blur effect applied to it already).  That seems like the least processor-intensive way to get the effect you want.

On the other hand, if your background is customisable and you still want to apply a blur effect, you could use the [Nokia Imaging SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk.html) ([also on Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NokiaImagingSDK)) to blur any image on the fly.  There is some patented technology inside that SDK that helps to keep processor / memory use to a minimum and therefore might make it usable for this kind of background effect.

[Example](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/filterfactory-class/filterfactory-methods/createblurfilter-method.html).